# Nav menu "pulled left" using Bootstrap: submenu also pulled left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a navigation bar with drop down menus. I've created the navigation bar and used bootstraps "pull-left" class to move it to the left. But the dropdown menu I have created using jQuery is now also moved the left since the HTML code is contained in the div marked as "pull-left" I have googled and tried out stuff for a few hours, but I couldn't quite find a solution.

The HTML for the Navigation bar

```
<div id = "nav">
    <div class = "container" >
            <div class = "pull-left ">
                <img class = "logo-image" src = "Logo2.png" />  
            </div>

            <ul class = "pull-left">
                <li class "logo"><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href = "#">About</a></li>
                <li>
                <a href = "#">Projects</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href = "#">Stealth Game </a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href = "#">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href = "#">Tutorials</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class = "pull-right">
                <li> <a href = "#">Follow me</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

The CSS

```
#nav li{
    display:inline;
    padding-right : 5px;
}

#nav ul ul { 
    display:none; 
    position:fixed; 
    z-index:999; 
}

#nav li li { 
    float: auto;
}

#nav li a { 
    width:150px; 
    display: inline-block; 
    text-align:center; 
    color:#000;
    margin-right:5px; 
    height:35px;
    line-height:35px;
    text-decoration:none; 
    font-size:80%;
    border:1px solid #ccc; 
 }

#nav ul{ 
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
 }



#nav li li a { 
    background:#EBE7E6!important;
    text-align:left; 
    height:auto; 
    line-height:1; 
    width:150px; 
    padding:8px 20px 8px 22px; 
    border:1px solid #D0D0D0; 
    border-top:none; 
    margin-right:0; 
}
```

And the JavaScript

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nav li:has(ul)").hover(function(){
        $(this).find("ul").slideDown();
    }, function(){
        $(this).find("ul").hide();
    });
});
```

So the actual problem is, that the submenu, that is appearing doesn't appear under the menu it is opened from, but is also pulled to the left since I used this bootstrap class to move my navigation bar to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things resolve this:

```
#nav li {
    display:inline-block;
    ...
}
#nav ul ul {
    position:absolute;
    ...
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/u9m536zm/)**

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
#nav ul ul { 
  display:none; 
  position:fixed; 
  z-index:999; 
}
```

The `position:fixed` on the submenu is probably what is giving you positioning problems.

edit:

you want to use `position: absolute` instead.

another edit, set `position: relative` on the parent LI, you will also need to set the display to block and because they are no longer inline elements you will want to float them left:

```
#nav li{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 5px;
 }
```

Fiddle with this working: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/

Comment: Did not fix the problem. It is still appearing under the home button instead of the project button, so it is still pulled left.

Comment: Im sorry, but it still didnt fix the problem. It is still appearing under the home screen even after changing both positons to what you suggested

Comment: Sorry about that here is a fiddle while I update my answer: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/